# Prim Algorithm optimized for known edge weights?

Tags: algorithm, prims-algorithm

How can you modify prim's algorithm in the case where you already know the minimum value of any given weight? For example if a graph consists of edge weights 0 and 1, how can you make prim's algorithm faster?

Comment: -> http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 6):

The first strategy would seem to be improving the priority queue to take advantage of your data. If you know that the weights are discrete values less than some C, you can replace the typically used binary heap with a radix heap. This way you can easily get the same algorithmic complexity as with the much more difficult to implement Fibonacci heap, or possibly even better. Dijkstra's algorithm uses the exact same data structures and here's a thorough explanation of how to implement a radix heap for it:

http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/tad.takaoka/alg/spalgs/radixheap.txt

Sample code radixheap.cpp can be found here:

http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/tad.takaoka/alg/spalgs/spalgs.html

You can simply apply the same data structure to Prim's algorithm as that text explains for Dijkstra's algorithm, to get complexity O(m + n log C) where m is edges, n is vertices and C is the maximum edge weight. If your edge weights are only small integers, this is very good indeed.

To summarize the idea of the radix heap, items are placed in buckets according to their priority (which must be integer). The range of values covered by bucket N is roughly sized 2^N so finding the right bucket is proportional to the log of the largest possible number. When extracting the item with smallest priority, items are sometimes redistributed to lower buckets which amortized also works out to logarithmic complexity.

If you meant that the edge weights are arbitrary floating point numbers between 0 and 1, that doesn't allow any optimization. Obviously any graph can be transformed by dividing all edge weights by the maximum edge weight, making them all between 0 and 1. This transformation cannot possibly make the Prim's algorithm run any faster. You can transform all edges by adding the same number to all of them, or multiplying them with the same positive number, without changing the result at all.